# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'. > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:28.1.0

Tags: android, react-native

Im facing this problem after upgrade react-native 0.59 to build 32 bit and 64 bit version

error when i try do run-android :

[image: error]

error when i do `./gradlew installDebug --info`

[image: error2]

this my code for `build.gradle`

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            name 'Google'
        }
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

def googlePlayServicesVersion = '15.0.1'

allprojects {
    repositories {
    google()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            name 'Google'
        }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
            }
        }
    }
}

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
}
```

`app/build.gradle`

```js
implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.1.0.'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation ('com.android.support:exifinterface:26.0.0-alpha1') {
        force = true;
    }

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0"
}
```

- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.59.0-rc.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update so many things in your configuration.

First, update google service version to `4.2.0` by updating this

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Also, update the build configuration

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
```

And the dependency update

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' // 28.0.0 is now live
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' // instead 28.1.0
```

Comment: keep geeting same error and in gradle instaldebug seems cant download that version and said resource missing , i make sure open this link : https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/28.0.0./support-v4-28.0.0..pom%5D

Comment: Unintentionally added an extra `.` after that. Now check again.

Comment: thanks you for help, now i can pass this and meet other error

Answer (score 0):

Add `google()` to below:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // <=== here    
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `28.1.0` of `support-v4`. The latest version of `com.android.support:support-v4` is `28.0.0` as per [maven.google.com](http://maven.google.com):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```